# Change (replace) word in metabox

Tags: plugins, php, woocommerce-offtopic

I use OMDBAPI to get information on my site. it work but I want to replace some word in my language.

This is metabox code:

```
add_filter('rwmb_meta_boxes', 'woocommerce_imdb_meta_boxes');

function woocommerce_imdb_meta_boxes($meta_boxes) {

    $meta_boxes[] = array(
        'title'      => __( 'IMDB', 'wc-imdb' ),
        'post_types' => 'product',
        'fields'     => array(
            array(
                'id'   => 'budget',
                'name' => __( 'budget', 'wc-imdb' ),
                'type' => 'text',
            ),
            array(
                'id'   => 'popularity',
                'name' => __( 'popularity', 'wc-imdb' ),
                'type' => 'text',
            ),
            array(
                'id'   => 'genre',
                'name' => __( 'genre', 'wc-imdb' ),
                'type' => 'text',
            ),
        ),
    );

    return $meta_boxes;

}

public static function find_field( $field_id, $post_id = null ) {
    $post_type = get_post_type( $post_id );
    if ( empty( self::$fields[$post_type] ) )
    {
        self::hash_fields( $post_type );
    }
    $fields = self::$fields[$post_type];
    if ( ! isset( $fields[$field_id] ) )
    {
        return false;
    }
    $field = $fields[$field_id];
    return RWMB_Field::call( 'normalize', $field );
}
```

For example, data in genre metabox is "Action, Drama, Mystery". So I wanted to replace any word in these custom field;

```
$engc = array(
    "Action",
    "Drama",
    "Mystery",
);
$farc = array(
    "اکشن",
    "درام",
    "معمایی"
);
genre = str_replace($engc, $farc);
```

Comment: the filter `rwmb_meta_boxes` is from the plugin "Meta Box"  : https://docs.metabox.io/

Comment: How are you displaying the value in the metabox?

Comment: I Edtied code above